# script for changing the webaddress in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I want to add the url of my university after the url of ieee or acm so that I can access the pdf of the research paper

how to do this?

e.g.

change a link like -

`ieee.org/paper21`

to

```
ieee.org.university.edu/paper21
```

what kind of bookmark should I create in chrome to automate this, instead of typing `.university.edu` every time after the `.org`

Comment: why don't you redirect from your javascript window.location = "ieee.org.university.edu/paper21"

Answer (score 1):

```
document.location = document.location.href.replace(
  document.location.host, 
  document.location.host + '.university.edu'
)
```

as a boomarklet

```
(function(){document.location=document.location.href.replace(document.location.host,document.location.host+'.university.edu');})()
```

or encoded that is

```
(function(){document.location=document.location.href.replace(document.location.host,document.location.host%2B'.university.edu');})()
```